# Installing Ubuntu 14.04 in Windows 8, the installation does not go further

Tags: software-installation, windows-8

I am using Boot CD to install Ubuntu 14.04  64 Bit in my Windows 8 Desktop. After I select the option "Install Ubuntu inside Windows 8". Within a minute it gives me message "Please take out the CD and press (Enter)". It does not install.

There is no other error. Where should I look out if any other error? I have sufficient disk space in C Drive where windows is installed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Answer (score 0):

Did you make another partition for Ubuntu? If you didn't, try making one by following these steps:

1. Boot into Windows 8 (you will make the partition here).
2. Search and open *Disk Management*.
3. Here you should see your Hard Drive, right-click it and select *Shrink a Basic Volume*. This will create another volume.
4. Once it is finished loading, you will be able to choose how big you want the volume to be. The wizard will show you what to do from there.
5. Once you finish the wizard, you should see that you have another volume. Now you can reboot your PC and try the installer again.

Answer (score 0):

When you say inside Windows 8, you mean a dual-boot option, right? If, you need to partition your hard drive in the "disk management" and do a formatted partition dedicated for Ubuntu. The allocated space depends on what you're going to do - but 10-15gb minimum I'd say. The Ubuntu installer should recognize the unallocated space now, and you should be able to install it on there.